# Edit an existing IIS IP Restriction with Powershell

Tags: iis, powershell, iis-7

I am writing a Powershell script to add/remove/edit IP restrictions for websites using Powershell. So far I am able to add restrictions, however wondering the best way to edit an existing ip restriction.

**Add**

```
Add-WebConfiguration -Filter /system.webserver/security/ipsecurity -Value @{ipAddress=$ipAddress;subnetMask="255.255.255.255";allowed=$allowed} -Location $websiteName -PSPath "IIS:\"
```

**Edit**

I have tried various combinations of:

```
Set-WebConfiguration -Filter system.webServer/security/ipSecurity/add[@ipAddress='192.123.123.123'] -Name "ipAddress" -Value $ipAddress -Location $websiteName -PSPath "IIS:\"

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter system.webServer/security/ipSecurity/add[@ipAddress='192.123.123.123'] -Value = @{ipAddress=$ipAddress;subnetMask="255.255.255.255";allowed=$allowed} -Location $websiteName -PSPath "IIS:\"
```

Is the best way essentially to clear all, and recreate each time?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it like this -

```
# Compose new entry    
$value = @{allowed="true";ipAddress="192.168.0.1"}

# Add new entry to restrictions
Add-WebConfigurationProperty  -Filter 'system.webServer/security/ipSecurity' -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\MySite\" -Location "MyService" -Name "." -Value $value -ErrorAction Stop
```